# Compare and Delete list objects based on key (float values)

Tags: python, list, filter, duplicates

I have a list of objects "repeated_words_list" & each object contains a dictionary having a word(string), start(float), end(float), conf(float)

I want to keep only 1 occurrence of each repeated word that has the highest p.start among all of its occurrences and remove all occurrences with lower p.start.

I have printed it like this

```
for p in repeated_words_list:
    print(f"{p.word} {p.start} - {p.end}")
```

Output

```
p.word p.start - p.end
the 0.27 - 2.91
the 25.38 - 25.5
the 26.94 - 27.24
the 27.66 - 27.81
the 38.67 - 38.705229
the 53.22 - 53.73
the 55.02 - 55.17
well 2.91 - 3.39
well 3.96 - 4.38
well 5.82 - 6.09
well 9.09 - 9.42
well 12.21 - 12.63
keeping 4.53 - 4.95
keeping 13.2 - 13.53
yourself 4.95 - 5.43
yourself 13.53 - 14.04
it 6.09 - 6.24
it 56.67 - 56.88
can 6.24 - 6.57
can 21.09 - 21.48
is 15.81 - 16.05
is 25.86 - 26.04
is 28.14 - 28.26
a 16.05 - 16.14
a 22.862336 - 22.89
see 54.764476 - 55.02
whether 61.35 - 61.71
whether 63.63 - 63.93
it's 61.71 - 62.07
it's 63.93 - 64.17
```

I tried this way but couldn't get this done since I am not able to access previous and next element.

```
for i in range(len(repeated_words_list)):
    if p[i].word == p[i-1].word:
        if p[i].start > p[i-1].start:
            repeated_words_list[i-1]= p[i].start
```

can some good soul guide me for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary which uses `word` as an index. If the index already exists, update the value only if a higher `start` value is found.

```py
final_words = {}
for p in repeated_words_list:
    word = final_words.get(p.word, None)
    if not word:
        final_words[p.word] = p 
    else:
        if word.start < p.start:
            final_words[p.word] = p

# to get highest values
for p in final_words.values():
    print(f"{p.word} {p.start} - {p.end}")

# for all words other than the one with highest occurence
for p in repeated_words_list:
    if final_words[p.word] != p:
        print(f"{p.word} {p.start} - {p.end}")
```

Comment: this does keep only 1 occurrence of each word but does not maintain its other attributes such p.start p.end p.conf in final_words

Comment: I get this output only dict_keys(['the', 'well', 'keeping', 'yourself', 'it', 'can', 'is', 'a', 'sense', 'but', 'couple', 'of', 'your', 'you', 'if', 'truth', 'that', 'now', 'remove', 'cover', 'and', 'see', 'whether', "it's"])

Comment: I tried this 
```
for p in final_words:
   print(f"{p.word} {p.start} - {p.end}")  
```
error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'word'

Comment: @KedNIMBALKAR you have to iterate over the values, and not the keys. Check the edited answer

Comment: @Abhinav note that this is a good opportunity to use `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: Can you add one more answer pls tell me how can I keep all lower occurrences except the highest occurrence

Comment: @mozway good point, what would you set as the default value for the dict?

Comment: You could use a dict, or another defaultdict of a dict. I haven't tested it ;)

Comment: @mozway that would work if OP was actually using a dict. Since they're using a custom class called `Word`, I decided to go with a simple dict

Comment: OK, I had read `dictionary` in the question, just seeing there was a comment now ;)

Comment: @Abhinav Can you add one more answer here pls tell me how can I keep all lower occurrences except the highest occurrence